# Excel 2013 64 Bit only use 12GB ram with 24 GB ram total

Tags: excel

im having some kind of trouble with my excel that its not using up all the ressource.
Im using Win 7 64bit with Excel 2013 64bit on the HP Workstation Z600 with 24 GB Ram. My problem is im writing Marco for very big Speadsheets and it always takes like 20-30 mins to complete but the computer isnt fully used at it potential i think. When i open task manager while excel is running, i see CPU only using 20-50% and Memory only 12GB. I checked the Setting in Excel and it says all 6 cores are alr available for excel to use. I just want to make excel use up all the potential of the computer to complete the task faster.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are your macros multithreaded? If not, then they will run sequentially instead of in parallel, so you will be taking advantage of only one of the cores available to Excel.

Comment: Use `VMMap` from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/vmmap to see the used RAM by Excel. Do you have 12GB free RAM or 12GB is used by Excel - reported by Task Manager?

Comment: Out of interest, what is the task? Knowing that would help me to suggest an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

That's life I'm afraid.

VBA runs in a single threaded apartment, so it only ever uses one core. And the Excel process itself puts limits on the amount of memory it will consume.

Comment: Only 32-bit Excel has hard memory limits. [As more RAM is added to the computer, \[64-bit\] Excel uses that additional memory, allows larger and larger workbooks, and scales with the amount of RAM available](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/excel-performance-and-limit-improvements).